# I want to fix a hump/a swollen part in Adobe After Effects on a lip. Whats the best way to fix it?

Tags: after-effects

It doesn't need muuuch fixing just to be a little more subtle. And also, it's relatively small part of the video so if its not pixel perfect it doesn't really matter.

How would I start to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this tool http://aescripts.com/paint-out/ it takes the pain out of painting out things. If you are not willing to pay the money you can use the basic [clone and stamp tools](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/paint-tools-brush-clone-stamp.html#clone_stamp_tool) of AE.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the Distort>Liquify effect.  Just like in photoshop.  You may want to consider putting it on an adjustment layer and tracking it in mocha if there is a lot of movement.   Here's a similar tutorial on mocha https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wwKQtxbLeH8